# How to convert a Mac Address to a Hex and pass it to a bytearray in java

Tags: java, android, hex

How can i convert a MacAddress to a Hex String and then parse it to a byte in java?
and similarly an IP Address as well?

Thank you

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. MAC addresses are already in hex, at least when written, and byte arrays don't contain hex, they contain binary. If you are getting the MAC address as text, you want to convert it *from* hex into binary. If you're getting it from an API, it already is binary, and it already is a byte array.

Comment: I'm assuming he had it in the form of a string, and needed characters converted to bytes...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A MAC address is already in hexadecimal format, it is of the form of 6 pairs of 2 hexadecimal digits.

```
String macAddress = "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF";
String[] macAddressParts = macAddress.split(":");

// convert hex string to byte values
Byte[] macAddressBytes = new Byte[6];
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    Integer hex = Integer.parseInt(macAddressParts[i], 16);
    macAddressBytes[i] = hex.byteValue();
}
```

And...

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.1.1";
String[] ipAddressParts = ipAddress.split("\\.");

// convert int string to byte values
Byte[] ipAddressBytes = new Byte[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(ipAddressParts[i]);
    ipAddressBytes[i] = integer.byteValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will parse both MAC addresses and IP addresses, and convert to bytes in a polymorphic manner.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

The following code will do what you are requesting:

```
    String ipv4Addr = "1.2.3.4";
    String ipv6Addr = "aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::";
    String macAddr = "a:b:c:d:e:f";
    try {
        HostIdentifierString addressStrings[] = {
            new IPAddressString(ipv4Addr),
            new IPAddressString(ipv6Addr),
            new MACAddressString(macAddr)
        };
        Address addresses[] = new Address[addressStrings.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < addressStrings.length; i++) {
            addresses[i] = addressStrings[i].toAddress();//parse
        }
        for(Address addr : addresses) {
            byte bytes[] = addr.getBytes();
            //convert to a list of positive Integer for printing
            List<Integer> forPrinting = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length).map(idx -> 0xff & bytes[idx]).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println("bytes for " + addr + " are " + forPrinting);
        }
    } catch(HostIdentifierException | IOException e) {
        //e.getMessage has validation error
    }
```

output:

```
    bytes for 1.2.3.4 are [1, 2, 3, 4]
    bytes for aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:: are [170, 170, 187, 187, 204, 204, 221, 221, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    bytes for 0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f are [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```