# Get bytes mac addres to wake on lan

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app to wake up on lan pc.

In this page I found a java example:
https://www.sistemasorp.es/2005/06/13/wake-on-lan-y-magic-packet/
but I am confused in how to get mac-address bytes.

How can get bytes?

In the web page:

```
**byte** mac[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};
```

In this question:
([How to convert a Mac Address to a Hex and pass it to a bytearray in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835773/how-to-convert-a-mac-address-to-a-hex-and-pass-it-to-a-bytearray-in-java))

```
**Byte**[] macAddressBytes = new Byte[6];
...
Integer hex = Integer.parseInt(macAddressParts[i], 16);
macAddressBytes[i] = hex.byteValue();
```

(Byte vs byte)

I do this code:

```
String output="";
byte mac1_1[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};
output+="mac1_1= "+mac1_1.toString()+"\n";
Byte mac1_2[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};
output+="mac1_2= "+mac1_2.toString()+"\n";
String mac2String="010203040506";
byte mac2_1[]=mac2String.getBytes();
output+="mac2_1= "+mac2_1.toString()+"\n";
String mac3 = "01:02:03:04:05:06";
String[] macAddressParts = mac3.split(":");
byte[] mac3_1 = new byte[6];
Byte[] mac3_2 = new Byte[6];
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    Integer hex = Integer.parseInt(macAddressParts[i], 16);
    mac3_1[i] = hex.byteValue();
    mac3_2[i] = hex.byteValue();
}
output+="mac3_1= "+mac3_1.toString()+"\n";
output+="mac3_2= "+mac3_2.toString()+"\n";
System.out.println(output);
```

and i get this result:

```
mac1_1= [B@106d69c

mac1_2= [Ljava.lang.Byte;@52e922

mac2_1= [B@25154f

mac3_1= [B@10dea4e

mac3_2= [Ljava.lang.Byte;@647e05
```

all bytes are different!

Someone knows which is correct?

Comment: Because toString is printing out the object hash code, not the value.

Comment: yes, right now I see...

Answer (score 0):

To get the MAC from your device use the `WifiManager` class

`WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);`

and then

`String mac = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress()`

Now simply call the method `getBytes(string)` from your mac variable

Get mac anddres from android only works in android api <= 21, for android M you can see this changelog

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id